# Storyboard ui elements don't appear in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios7, uielement

I have transitioned my iPad application from iOS 6 to iOS 7 and I had to turn off auto layout or the whole application would crash when I selected to view the storyboard.

Now that I can view it, all the uielements don't appear in the each storyboard screen.

The screens are there but they are blank (white). The editor shows that they are there but I cannot view them at all.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would help...

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to be allowed to add screenshot.

Comment: try uploading your image to dropbox.com and share the public to the image in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/4pz2q9dhxtc0f6w/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-30%20at%201.27.18%20PM.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the width and height/ x and y coordinate of the views. That fixed the same problem for me.