# Xcode 5 issue with xib, subviews are not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have a project developed with older version of Xcode , now i upgraded to Xcode 5 and opened the project and i faced a weird issue, I can't see subviews in some of the xib files, it is showing white background of parent UIView and nothing else showing up of its subviews.

Comment: Did you customize any view like alert view in the view controller where the white background is display?

Comment: Is it your UITableview cell or custom tableview cell?

Comment: No, I changed nothing, just opened up the project and clicked on the xib file, but i could see nothing in subviews of a UIView in that xib file.

Comment: It is just a UIView having subviews in a xib , but those subviews are not visible at all.

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101104/storyboard-ui-elements-dont-appear-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I fixed it by viewing the storyboard's XML by Right-Clicking the "MainStoryboard.storyboard" file and selecting "Open As", then "Source Code".  Found the view, but looked normal.  Just to test, I added a blank line, saved and everything in the view started working.  I may have changed the height number as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my case it's a xib file not the storyboard, I right-clicked on the xib file and selected the option of "Source Code" and changed something in a file and saved but nothing changed, still i am saying a white view and nothing else.

Comment: Hmm, ok, well my last suggestion is this.  In my case the subviews where in a view, and I'm sure the view was the issue.  I would insert another view and move the subviews into it. Try moving one subview and test.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime during xcode upgrade width or height of UIView (or any subview) gets changed. Look for height and width of your view in `size inspector` and you might be able to figure out the issue. You might need to change x/y coordinates or constraints as well to make your view completely visible.

PS: I've experienced this problem in storyboard but i believe that xib might have same sort of solution.